# What Linux distros support mmap_shared?

Tags: linux, mmap

I found a man page for a function called `mmap_shared` on `die.net`: https://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap_shared

It looks like a convenience wrapper function around `mmap`, however it doesn't seem to be available on Ubuntu 18.04, and I can't find much information about it anywhere else. What Linux distros support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is nothing a linux distro cares about. That's some ... niche function offered by a rather niche library, [libowfat](https://www.fefe.de/libowfat/). Which in itself is a re-implementation of libdjb, which is even more obscure. It comes from the author of an alternative libc, dietlibc, so you need to look at it from that perspective.

So, you need libowfat-dev (which *is* packaged by Debian and thus available in Ubuntu), you need to include the right headers, and you might or might not want to use dietlibc instead of glibc.

Frankly, while Fefe is quite proud of it being performant as memory management library underlying a few project such as OpenTracker, from a maintainability perspective, I'd be skeptical about using a C library for memory management that a single person develops for his own purposes and source-controls on cvs.

There's millions of library functions that are documented out there. As you said, this seems just to be a non-standard interface to `mmap` syscalls. Great reason to *not* include a whole library!